# iOS navigation title doesn't show on subpage

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, title

I have an app tab based with a navigation controller,

the title in the navigation bar shows fine in the root page for the tab,

but when I push another view controller, on top, I cannot set the title for this view

this is the code I use for the root page and the pushed page,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
UILabel *lava = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)]autorelease];
    lava.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lava.text = @"About us"; 

lava.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter ;
lava.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lava.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DroidSans-Bold" size:(46)];
lava.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lava.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 3);
self.navigationItem.titleView = lava;

 }
```

so, what is missing to set my title on the nav bar?

thanks!

Comment: Do you call your code in viewDidLoad or somewhere else?

Comment: @xapslock yes in viewDidLoad , I edited the question thanks

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Nav. item: %@", self.navigationItem);` say?

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks, for the root page:Nav. item: <UINavigationItem: 0x8916700>; and for the sub page: Nav. item: <UINavigationItem: 0x8a393b0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView`

Or if you use iOS5 or later..

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarBackground.png"];    
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f],UITextAttributeFont
                    ,[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor
                    ,[UIColor blackColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor
                    ,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset
                    , nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:dict];
```

Call this once in `viewDidLoad` in your rootViewController and then you can just use `self.title=@"foo"` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you should change title in the new controller viewDidLoad

Comment: yes thanks, i have the title for each view controller, is this what you mean?

Comment: try self.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = lava ; , also be sure that it is not nil

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect applicationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);
UIView * newView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame] autorelease];
[newView addSubview: lava];
self.navigationItem.titleView = newView;
```

Try like this. I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to push the view controller on top?

There is a difference between:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

so if you're using the presentModalViewController method, it won't show your title.

If that's not the issue and you're using the pushViewController method, you could try setting the title of the view controller you're pushing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Controller title";
}
```